# Windows, How yo protect a command window from keystrokes or mouseclicks?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-prompt

I occasionally leave a command window (on Windows, XP or 7) up and running for hours while doing things like massive builds, etc.  I just noticed I'd halted a window and the program running in it by accidentally clicking in it and marking a random bit of text.  Guess the command prompt expected a mouse click to copy out the text and I didn't supply it.

So, what I'm looking for is not easy to find.  Nothing I can think of to search on is going to get me an answer that isn't about some other aspect of computing:  protector, shield, etc.

So, it there such a program?  I envision something that wraps around the window in question and is transparent (i.e. I can read through it) but it intercepts any keystrokes or mouse clicks aimed at the window "inside" it.

Comment: Do you want to protect a program you made, or a third party program?

Comment: Just clicking on the window is not the problem, right-clicking is going to mark text.  Is it likely that you will right click in normal use?

Comment: One would guess it'd be unlikely.  I did it anyway  Part of my problem is I have shorter fingers that the person who designed the Magic Mouse.  Consequently my index finger tends to sit where the middle finger should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try redirecting the output of your console application to a file (this is simple to do from the command-line without any programming).

Alternatively, you can write a small front-end (C# would be pretty simple) that has a read-only textbox. When this front-end starts up, it launches your command-line program and redirects its output, to be shown in the textbox.

Both of these solutions are simple to implement - the file is simpler but you can't read the output while the console program is running, only afterwards. With the UI front-end, you can have the textbox update and scroll as the console program is generating output. The UI option also allows you to hide the real console window and only have your UI front-end window visible.

If your console program needs input as well, it's quite a bit more complicated but based on your description, it's not the case. I don't know of a ready-made utility for this but even if you have to do it yourself, it's probably less than 200 lines of (not very complex) code in C# or VB.Net.

Comment: Redirection is problematic.  The programs in question are already running inside MinGW/MSYS, the Linux Compilers on Windows solution  and Linux environment emulator, and the scripts it is running (and the scripts those script run.....) already have some redirection to /dev/null and elsewhere.  Also, theer is the stdout/stderr 2>&1 problem to address.  Your idea to let a C# program wrap the Window sounds great.  Not all I've got to do is learn c#....  I have this picture that looks like a see-through envelop wrapped around the "console" window.

Comment: @WesMiller That's not exactly what I had in mind but I see how it'd be useful. Your idea is also doable in C# but it'll be more work because you'll have to keep track of the position of the console window and if it's minimized, etc. This is why I recommended redirecting the output stream of your top-level console window (I assume that's MinGW). You should be able to redirect that easily. Whatever redirections are done by that window is of no concern to you.